# Pandoc not handling in-text citation with certain csl file

Tags: citing, conversion, pandoc, markdown

Here's an example input markdown file:

```
@brandt2009two, observing programmers building an online chat room in the lab, 
found that online resources are leveraged primarily to engage in *just-in-time 
learning* of new skills and approaches, *clarify and extend* their existing 
knowledge, and *remind* themselves of details deemed not worth remembering 
[@brandt2009two].
```

As per [the docs](http://pandoc.org/demo/example19/Extension-citations.html), I expect the first citation to appear without brackets, citing the author's name, and the second one to appear in brackets. That's what happens when using pandoc with no special options:

```
pandoc in.md --bibliography library.bib -o out.pdf
```

But I'd like to use ACM's citation style, so in the output, the in text citation should appear as "Brandt et al (2009), observing programmers...", and the regular one should appear as "[1]".

However, when adding a csl option, both citations appear as "[1]":

```
pandoc pandoc.md --smart --standalone --bibliography library.bib --template=proceedings.tex --csl=acm-sig-proceedings.csl -o out.pdf
```

Here's the csl file: https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/acm-sig-proceedings.csl

Comment: Can you also post the resulting `.tex` file? It seems like you are not (or cannot?) rely on `natbib` or `biblatex` to construct your PDF.

Comment: Which `acm-sig-proceedings.csl` file are you using. The one available [here](https://github.com/jakobib/pandoc-acm-templates) uses numbers as references. So, you need to select some other citation style that uses author years.

Comment: @jon This happened to me too today with the following CSL: https://www.zotero.org/styles/din-1505-2-alphanumeric
Pandoc leaves the square brackets simply empty and it seems to be the only style which abbreviates this nicely on the zotero style archive.

Comment: @Zelphir -- Can you post a new question about this? It will need to contain a very minimal `.md` file with a citation, a `.bib` entry for that citation, the `pandoc` command you used to create the `.tex` file, and the resulting `.tex` file from the conversion.

Comment: @jon It would have the very same title though. Not sure it's a good practice. It should be the case with any markdown source containing citations, which you use with that CSL. I'll see to making an example.

Comment: @Zelphir -- You need to make an example, and you shouldn't edit this question. So the only option is to make a new question (just put your CSL file name in parenthesis, maybe, to disambiguate. And you can link back to this question -- which would be helpful in general.) Please include your `pandoc` version, too.

Comment: @jon http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340649/92107 Hope this serves as a MWE.