# Pandoc not handling in-text citation with certain CSL file correctly

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I was asked in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331138/92107) to open a new question with a MWE for a CSL file, which is not handled correctly by Pandoc Citeproc or Pandoc.

First of all the call to Pandoc I use:

```
pandoc \
--read=markdown \
--filter pandoc-citeproc \
--bibliography=bibliography.bib \
--csl=din-1505-2-alphanumeric.csl \
--output citation-example.pdf \
citation-example.md
```

I use the following Pandoc version:

```
pandoc 1.18
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.8.6.6, highlighting-kate 0.6.3
Default user data directory: /home/user/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2016 John MacFarlane 
Web:  http://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

I use the following pandoc-citeproc version:

```
pandoc-citeproc 0.10.2.2
```

And the `.bib` file referenced contains:

```
@article{chou_interactivity_2003,
    title={Interactivity and interactive functions in web-based learning systems: a technical framework for designers},
    author={Chou, Chien},
    journal={British Journal of Educational Technology},
    volume={34},
    number={3},
    pages={265--279},
    year={2003},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

And the referenced CSL file I got from [here](https://www.zotero.org/styles/din-1505-2-alphanumeric).

And the referenced Pandoc Markdown source code:

```
# Lorem Ipsum

"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet [@chou_interactivity_2003 p. 10], consectetur, adipisci velit..."

# References
```

And a screenshot of the produced PDF:

[image]

And a screenshot of the preview on Zotero website:

[image]

As you can see the only thing rendered in the in-text citation is what is not the citation key, but what else I wrote there.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Why are you posting this here? It has nothing to do with TeX.  The place for this question is pandoc-discuss on Google Groups.

Comment: @JohnMacFarlane Yeah could've posted it there too - probably would've soon and will soon, if there is no good solution here. I tend to like the stackexchange websites more, because the editor actually works well and one can create better looking questions. Overall more comfort. I also posted here, because I initially found the linked question here. I also mentioned the issue in here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/wO_rJPBZoBo but I admit, MWE did not exist then. Sometimes one can find pandoc things here, because people here also sometimes use pandoc.

Comment: Sounds like `pandoc` people are going to take over. But, for future reference, a key piece of information for this site is the resulting `.tex` file. (Although the solutions you get here are likely to focus on how to use BibTeX or Biber/`biblatex` to generate the bibliography rather than a CSL file, so maybe  this doesn't matter as much.)

Answer (score 1):

I can only confirm what you found and the problem lies in the csl file. It is not compatible with pandoc-citeproc (I haven't tested with tex though). The solution is either edit it manually or change to other version of the same style.